# How to sorted custom with pagination pageable JPA Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I have table `m_customer`, I want to sort by with newest data (updated_at is not null) or `created_at` (if the data is new, never updated)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just set updated_at equal to created_at for new records and then just sort by updated_at column?

Comment: I can't change the data